# No Module Found python (run outside IDE)

Tags: python, module, pycharm

I'm trying to run a script outside pycharm and this is what happens
[my command prompt when i try to run the main.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cIr3j.png)

```
C:\Users\Beatriz\PycharmProjects\Tese\Main> python main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "main.py", line 1, in <module>
from View.view import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'View'

C:\Users\Beatriz\PycharmProjects\Tese\Main>
```

I put each file in a package like this:
[files_packaging](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ph0tO.png)

Still it seems not recognize the module "View"

my main code:

```
from View.view import *

if __name__ == "__main__":
    View()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way is to move the contents of the `Main` folder outside of it, directly inside the `Test` folder where all the other folders are. That way you can directly invoke `from View.view import *`.

To run the script:

```py
cd PycharmProjects/Tese
python main.py
```

Comment: i tried and it happened
'  File "main.py", line 1, in <module>
    from ..View.view import *
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package'